# How to change the icon of QFileDialog windows

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change the icon of the windows generated by the static methods of QFileDialog like getOpenFileName.

In the parameters of those static methods there isn't one to change that.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Write custom dialog , [something 
 similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426603/qt-customizing-save-file-dialog?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: the feature I need is static, so deriving won't help

Comment: In my opinion, it is impossible  without using an other method, and as Mohammad say, write a custom dialog or sublassing QDialogFile. As you say, the method is static and call directly the dialog, so no way to change the icone before the dialog is shown.